# Recyclerview with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter deselects selected item when item gets updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a RecyclerView to display items that can be selected. However, when the selected item gets updated through a Firestore transaction, the selection dissapears. I assume that it is calling notifyItemChanged on the item that gets updated, but I don't know how to retain it's selected status. I am using this code to select items:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int currentPosition = holder.getLayoutPosition();
        if(selectedPosition != currentPosition){
            // Temporarily save the last selected position
            int lastSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
            // Save the new selected position
            selectedPosition = currentPosition;
            // update the previous selected row
            notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
            // select the clicked row
            holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
});
```

and this code to highlight the layout:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Color when the row is selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Standard background color -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by storing a value from the previously selected item and looping through all items and deselecting them if they contained that value which is not ideal but it works for now.